# Как передать звук в микрофон?

Tags: java

Как я могу передать звук в микрофон? (Типа как в Soundpad)
Информацию о том как захватить звук с микрофона я нашел, а вот как передать туда звук - нет.

Comment: Я в данном вопросе некомпетентен, поэтому возможно спрошу глупость, но зачем передавать звук в... микрофон?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак.

Микрофон - это источник звука. с него можно звук только брать. И самое главное - ему просто нечем воспроизводить звук.

Возможно, Вы имеете в виду, что Вам надо заменить звук "с микрофона" каким то своим звуком?

После ответа Maxgmer и комментариев, я решил дополнить свой ответ.

Обычно чтобы "завернуть" звук в программу, используется так называемый "[виртуальный кабель](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Audio_Cable)"

При его использовани у Вас в компьютере появляется дополнительное "устройство".

Я практически развлекался с такой вот [реализацией](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/), которая предназначена для винды, и выглядит это при установке примерно как на [image: картинке]:

Правда, у меня совершенно нет опыта того, как работать со звуком на Java, но вот для более привычного мне .NET есть библиотека [naudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio), и есть интересные [примеры](https://markheath.net/post/how-to-record-and-play-audio-at-same) работы с ней

Comment: Да, это я и хотел узнать

Comment: "ему просто нечем воспроизводить звук" - вот тут вы не правы. И там и там катушки, и там и там мембраны. Отличие примерно такое же как между электромотором и электрогенератором.

Comment: @Kromster - да, но микрофонный вход не способен генерировать напряжение. Можно, конечно, углубиться в схемотехнику самой материнки, но мне кажется, здесь это лишнее. Кроме того, есть конденсаторные микрофоны - в них нет катушки. И, конечно, я пишу не из желания поспорить, а только для полноты картины :-)

Comment: Решил вопрос с помощью виртуального кабеля, спасибо)

Answer (score 5):

Наверное вы имели в виду не передать звук в микрофон, а сделать так, чтобы система получила звук из микрофона, но этот звук был получен не из микрофона, а из другого источника (например, из файла).

Система получает ввод с микрофона от драйвера микрофона, он говорит ей, какой звук "услышал" микрофон. Переписав драйвер, можно сделать так, чтобы драйвер говорил что угодно.

В вашем случае, вам скорее всего переписывать драйвер было бы не практично, так как девайсы бывают разные и драйвера у них разные.

Для вашего кейса вам бы подошел виртуальный драйвер микрофона, который бы передавал любые звуки системы. Если вы не писали драйвера никогда, может быть довольно сложно.

Вы будете работать с протоколом ASIO, это протокол передачи данных от аппаратной части к софту, только потоком ввода у вас будет не аппаратная часть, а файл или что-то еще.

Вот нашел [Java враппер для ASIO](https://github.com/mhroth/jasiohost), можете начать копать отсюда.