# Как передать звук в микрофон?(Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Ранее, я уже задавал подобный вопрос - [ТЫК](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267282/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD).

Но разница в том, что в прошлый раз это нужно было реализовать на десктопе, в этот же раз это нужно сделать под Андроид. Там это было реализовано с помощью виртуального кабеля, в этой версии такой вариант не подойдет.
В интернете, к сожалению, ничего не нашел :(

Comment: Микрофон не издает звуки. Звуки издают динамики

Comment: @ArtyMorris, вот [правильный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1267299/232) по сути этого вопроса

Comment: Так какой вопрос, такоиэй и ответ )